# Why did Lennox pledge his allegiance the way he did?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-the-last-knight

I didn't really understand that plot twist.

> Why does Lennox and his team decided to team up with Megatron?

I could understand the whole government anti-transformer policy based on the previous movie. Also the fact that he doesn't know Cade. But he does know Bumblebee, and he worked with him! That alone should have been enough to rethink the whole negotiation thing.

Comment: Maybe he thinks all robots look the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General Morshower explained it clearly to Lennox, when discussing the plan.

They would negotiate with Megatron purely to use Megatron's ability to hunt down the location of the Staff. After they got the location, their ceasefire with Megatron would be over and they'd take him out, and get the staff for themselves.

You can see that the military didn't fully cooperate with Megatron, as they did deny him one of his chosen Decepticons (Berserker). And Santos clearly said to Lennox that after they got what they needed for Megatron, he was going to take him down.

So, it was merely a tactical choice. Humans didn't have the resources to locate the staff before Cybertron's arrival, so they needed to team up with someone who did know. At that point, Megatron was their only option considering the Autobots didn't even seem to be aware that the staff existed.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Pretty sure that's just a regular old expression devoid of intrinsic reference to Hitler.

Comment: I, for one, had no idea that the ancient European legends about Faust were references to Hitler.